# Multiple video playing issue in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app I am trying to play multiple videos in `UITableViewCell` for this I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` it plays the video without any issue. but it play one video at a time and in other cell I get black screen suppose at first time one cell is visible it play the video but as soon as I scroll for second row the first cell video view disappear with black screen. I am not getting how to make all video view visible even if I scroll the table view. this is the code I am using for play video in custom cell :

**Custom Cell initialization :**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self){
        NSArray *nibArray=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self=[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        _player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
        _player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [_player setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://files.parse.com/ef5649ee-75c6-4c76-ba3b-37be4d281125/b35589f7-c0aa-4ca8-9f7c-fd31b2dc8492-vedioTeaser.mov"]];
        [_player prepareToPlay];
        [_player play];
        [self addSubview:_player.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }else{
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @vinod - did you find an elegant solution for this eventually? I'm struggling with this too (I need controls so raw AVFoundation is no good)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `AVFoundation framework` for playing multiple videos simultaneously .
A step by step and full source code on how to do this: [multiple-video-playback-on-ios](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/)

You can't use `MPMoviePlayerController`. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that clearly..

> Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.

hope it helps you.

Comment: in the source code it uses different controllers to play movie not one.